# Angular / Typescript get only 1 record and a value of it's id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have some data in a variable which looks like this on chrome console:

```
0:
@attributes:
    actPer: "1",
    id: "19"
1:
@attributes:
    actPer: "1"
    id: "17"
etc
```

To filter I used:

```
myvar = this.obj.listResponse.instance;
```

Up to there all ok.

What I now need to do it to just get the 1st item and get the id value of that item.

How can I do this?

Comment: `myVar[0]['@attributes'].id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing much of your data structure, but hopefully this works for you:

```js
const obj = {
    listResponse: {
        instance: [
            { '@attributes': { actPer: '1', id: '19' } },
            { '@attributes': { actPer: '1', id: '17' } }
        ]
    }
};

console.log(obj.listResponse.instance[0]['@attributes'].id);
```

It returns `'19'`.